# Are bits in Page Table Entry padded with 0 to get a location in Physical Memory ?(Newbie)

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-tables

Considering multilevel paging, If we have a physical address of 32 bits, say 24 bits are allocated for frame number. Whenever a Virtual address is generated, it goes to Page Table and the PTE is 24 bits(ignore control bits) gives frame no. But these 24 bits cannot actually find an address .
So my question is, Are these 24 bits right padded with zeros to reach the base address of that frame ?